# Can we use Sock Js library to only implement HTML5 SSE?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, server-sent-events, sockjs

So as i look at Sock Js GitHub documentation [sockjs-client supported-transports-by-name](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#supported-transports-by-name), HTML5 SSE is supported by the library.
My questions are:
1. Can i use Sock Js library when i only want to implement HTML5-SSE? If yes how to set them up?

```
  //From documentation

    var sockjs = new SockJS(url, _reserved, options);

  /*
    Where options parameter is a hash which can contain:
    .....
    transports (string OR array of strings)
    Sometimes it is useful to disable some fallback transports. This option allows you to supply a list
    transports that may be used by SockJS. By default all available transports will be used.
    ....
  */

  Thus, can i just go like this:

  var sockjs = new SockJS("url://", ["eventsource", "iframe-eventsource"]);

  //Also, what does the __reserved parameter is meant to do?
```

2. On the [Supported Transports By Browser](https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-client#supported-transports-by-browser-html-served-from-http-or-https), there are no list "eventsource"/"iframe-eventsource" supported by any browser given on list. So, how does this all mean?
3. Furthermore, is it considered to be okay to use Sock Js in such purpose? If not, what would be the best implementation of HTML5-SSE?